# Amazon AWS server with database on localhost, how do I ssh so that my php webservices on localhost can run on it?

Tags: php, mysql, amazon-web-services, ssh

Server newbie here!

I have access to an amazon AWS server, and I have a php webservice on my localhost. The php is working properly on the webservice. The MySQL is set up on the server. However, I cannot connect to my server. I set up everything on the amazon AWS server by SSH-ing in to it and working from there. Is there a way to allow me to ssh into the server with my webservice?

Just to reiterate: 
-My php script is at localhost/ ... 
-My server is accessed by ssh and then on my localhost, it is hosted by amazon aws (default port 3306)

I attempted the process suggested by one user which was to enter the following into my terminal:

ssh -L 8080:127.0.0.1:3306 -f -C -q -N -i ./password.pem user@host.com

and then when I used mysqli connect I entered:

new mysqli('127.0.0.1:8080','root','mypassword');

Thanks so much for any assistance!

Comment: Well first of all, let's talk about running MySQL on an AWS instance. I am guessing that you would like to have your DB data persisted right?  Are you using EBS volume for storage of MySQL binary data?  If not, you will lose all your data at some point.  I would strongly encourage you to think about using RDS for your DB needs.

Comment: @MikeBrant Hi, I would like the DB data to not be deleted. I have an SQL dump that I used to load all the data into the database with, so no data will actually be lost if I butcher the DB a bit. I currently do have RDS and EC2. I don't really know how this helps though, can you help me with connecting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you are trying to connect to your remote database from your local server (if I understand correctly). You want to double check your security groups in AWS that they are allowing your computers ip address to connect to the server instance / that port 3306 is open to your pc. If that is all set, then you should be able to connect to the instance using the **public dns** or elastic ip if it is an EC2 instance, or the **endpoint** if it is an RDS instance.

Comment: Hi - I appreciate the help, but I need a lot more clarification. How exactly would I connect using the public DNS or elastic IP? This is an EC2 instance.

Comment: Well you probably want your db in an RDS instance, but to connect to the EC2 instance, simply use the public dns or elastic ip (if you have associated an elastic ip) instead of your localhost in your connection script. 

`new mysqli('ec2-12-345-67-89.compute-1.amazonaws.com', 'user', 'pwd', 'db')`

Have you configured your security group for the EC2 instance already?

Comment: Thanks for the help thus far! I tried the code offered (with my own host name, of course) but the connection failed. I'm not sure what you meant by security groups in AWS - Is this something done through aws.amazon.com to override the need for an SSH connection?

Comment: You need to edit the security group for your ec2 instance to allow connections to your IP on port 3306. Use 3306 for port range, and your PC's IP address with a `/32` after it for the source, ie: `12.345.67.89/32`

Comment: Thank you so much for your patience! :) I'd upvote your answer but I'm too new right now to do so.

Comment: When specifying which connection to allow, should I be selecting TCP/UDP/or MYSQL, etc?